# Is there any framework/library available to implement "take a tour" feature for my iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm implementing an app and i want to create "Take a tour" feature for my app, It will show up to user when he launches the app for the first time, I don't wanna put some screens on pageViewController and just scroll them. I wanna implement like most website does even few iOS apps i have seen but couldn't recall right now.

Comment: Why delay the user using your app? Why not just let them in and make the app so that it doesn't need a tour. It shouldn't be so hard to use that it requires a tour in the first place.

Comment: This is kind of time based event app. Event gets over in 2-3 days, User couldn't even figure out what all the important feature added to that app.

Comment: You need to explain more details if you hope to get clear answer:)

Comment: looking for some better version of this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mmpoplabel

Answer (score 2):

You can search here for a helper libraries https://www.cocoacontrols.com/

I'm sure you find something to perfectly fit your needs.

Maybe this library will be useful https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/myintroductionview

Or this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/myblurintroductionview

Or maybe this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/aotutorial

Comment: Thanks for your response but the link you have provided are the same like putting some screens on pageViewController.

Comment: "Take a tour" feature in the most cases is implemented by paging views. You haven't explained exactly what kind of behavior do you need. So I found some solutions for you. You always can go to the google and search if you need something else.

Comment: looking for some better version of this. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mmpoplabel